# It it possible to use wildcard certificate to sign subdomain certificate?

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, wildcard-subdomain

I am owner of wildcard certificate (public and private key) for ***.name.com**
Is it possible to use my certificate to generate another key pair for **subdomain.name.com** ?

I do not want to use my wildcard certificate *.name.com for subdomain.name.com directly.
subdomain.name.com will be managed by another division, and I do not want to share private key for with them *.name.com.

Is this setup supported, or do I have to buy certificate for subdomain.name.com ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to have different details on same certificate.

Wildcard certificate for all the sub-domain which is been secured by the certificate will show the same information.

So in your case you need to get a New SSL Certificate for the particular wildcard domain which you wish to secure.

Answer (score 3):

You have to get a new one.

(But your certificate may decide to give it for free, or you can buy one from any provider, or you can get free one from letsencrypt.org)